# need help in creating rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have been trying to create a rule for dynamic sub-domains and tried many rules given by other users. I am able to use dynamic sub-domains and they are working fine now.

My sub-domain structure is sub1.sub2.domain.com

Now i want that when a user goes to sub1.sub2.domain.com then the default page must be code.php and not index.php

Also in address bar only  sub1.sub2.domain.com should be visible and not  sub1.sub2.domain.com/code.php

Also i have to use two level sub-domains not single sub.domain.com

I just need help in creating the rewrite rule which displays code.php when user accesses  sub1.sub2.domain.com

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in .htaccess

```
# Provide Specific Index Page (Set the default handler)
DirectoryIndex code.php
```

Edit: In your index.php page, before your HTML try something like this:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'example.com' || $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'www.example.com'){
     header('Location: /index.php');
}else{ 
     header('Location: /code.php');
}
```

This should look at the server name, including sub-domain and work out what to use from there from memory.

Comment: hi,thank you for the answer but i want to use index page as if the user navigates to domain.com then he should be able to view contents accordingly.

Comment: So the directory with the file(s) for the sub-domains is also the site web root?

Comment: @Rajneesh Rana an alternative is now in the answer also

Comment: i am doing this in wordpress and i thought of another way out.
i added some custom code and imported code.php within index.php when the user is visiting the sub domain. Thank You